# Является ли С массив потокобезопасным (thread-safe) ?

Tags: ios, c, многопоточность, posix

Предположим у меня есть простая C строка:

```
char *str = "I am a string".
```

**Вопрос:** можно ли обращаться (чтение? запись?) из разных потоков к разным символам этой строки - будет ли это вызывать какие-либо проблемы в связи с конкурентным доступом?

**Вопрос 2:** есть ли разница в ответе, если массив конечный или динамический ?

**Вопрос 3:** Я предполагаю что ответы на вопросы 1 и 2, какими бы они ни были, будут универсальными для С массивов всех видов, не только строк. Это так?

P.S. В iOS для работы с потоками используется библиотека GCD (Grand Central Dispatch), в основе которой лежат POSIX Threads, поэтому я полагаю, что ответ для чистого C подойдёт и для iOS.

---

Спасибо.

Comment: Нет, не является, т.к. не предполагает каких-либо инструментов синхронизации доступа, собственно, это и не объект, чтобы иметь какой-либо дополнительный функционал (и слава богу!).

Comment: @mega, обратите внимание: три вопроса у меня - я их типа ещё специально жирным выделил: 1-2-3. Можете как-то подтвердить то, что Вы написали? Например, того, что вы написали следует, что мне нужны мьютексы, если я одним потоком пойду по нечётным индексам этой строки, а другим - по чётным, и оба потока просто будут читать то, что записано по этим индексам?

Comment: @avp, @Free_ze, отвечаю здесь из-за лимита:

@avp, понял, спасибо за комментарии.

@Free_ze, спасибо за разъяснение, - я просто не сразу отследил, как мы от доступа к массиву перешли к malloc. Теперь ясно.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, изучать и пробовать эти штуки, конечно, надо.

Только не забывайте, что 

    threads are evil

Можете прямо набрать это в гугле и почитать.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, полагаю, мой ответ на Ваш основной вопрос дает ответы и на дополнительные, кроме третьего, разве что, который мне не понятен. В деталях, конечно @VladD и @Free_ze правы по поводу неатомарности переменной.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Только для чтения массив потокобезопасен.
2. Если разные треды будут строго записывать только в разные элементы, то потокобезопасен.
3. Приведенный Вами вариант создания строки не совсем корректен, поскольку Вы создаете указатель, содержащий адрес константной строки. При обращении к ней на запись программа может вылететь.
    Надо делать так

   ```
   char str[] = "I am a string";
   ```

Comment: > 3. Приведенный Вами вариант создания строки не совсем корректен

Да, Вы правы. Задавая вопрос, я имел в виду чтение, и потом уже в конце перед публикацией дописал 'запись', как вариант, а форму записи строки оставил прежнюю.

Comment: > Если разные треды будут строго записывать только в разные элементы, то потокобезопасен.
Вы уверены? Мне кажется, процессор может обновлять какой-то кусок памяти целиком (например слово) при записи одного char.

Comment: >Мне кажется, процессор может обновлять какой-то кусок памяти целиком (например слово) при записи одного char.

Да, он будет обновлять кэш-линию (обычно 32/64 байта). Причем, всякий раз, перед использованием очередной кэш-линии, процессор будет вынужден запрашивать ее целиком из памяти [очень долго] или из кэша более низкого уровня [чуть быстрее], если другой процессор ее изменит. Т.е. если задача стояла повысить таким образом скорость обработки строки, увы - так не получится.

Comment: @mega, я бы добавил, что результат все равно будет *корректный* (т.е. если мы изменяем один байт, то соседние байты **не меняются**).

Answer (score 6):

Понятия потокобезопасности в отрыве от паттерна использования **не существует**.

Рассмотрим даже не массив, а переменную типа `int`. Потокобезопасна ли она? Правильный ответ — зависит от семантики использования. Если мы в ней храним упакованными два числа типа `char`, то вполне может быть ситуация, когда мы обновили одно, но не обновили другое, и другой поток увидит данные в неконсистентном виде. Или мы храним там индекс элемента в другом, потокобезопасном массиве. Потокобезопасна ли переменная? Нет, т. к. другой поток может увидеть значение переменной, большее максимального количества элементов массиве.

Вопрос о потокобезопасности можно ставить лишь после того, как вы определили семантику вашего кода.

[Дополнительное чтение по теме](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe) (там про C#, но всё применимо и к Objective C).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за разъяснение. Текущая семантика такая: есть на входе строка `char *` известной длины. Я сегодня в первый раз задумался над тем, можно ли организовать енумерацию по этой строке в два или более потока (только чтение элементов этой строки из обоих потоков) так, чтобы можно было реально выиграть в скорости по сравнению с обычной энумерацией. Apple GCD API позволяют очень быстро организовать любое количество потоков и вот я задумался: во-первых, не возникнет ли проблем с доступом к разным байтам этой строки, во-вторых, как эффективно разбить эту строку (пополам? чётные-нечётные?)

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: Смотрите. Если вы доступаетесь к каждому элементу поодиночке, у вас есть проблема синхронизации только между двумя потоками: тем, который записал данные в ячейку массива, и тем, который читает их оттуда. То есть

* если читающий поток стартует после того, как запись произошла, читать можно без ограничений
* если читающий поток стартовал, а запись ещё не произошла, необходимо гарантировать, что изменения видны в читающем потоке. Для этого нужно либо mutex, либо хотя бы memory barrier.

Comment: @VladD, понимаю, что вы описываете. У меня более простой случай: строка уже есть в готовом виде, далее ожидается только чтение этой строки из нескольких потоков. На основе всех ответов/комментариев в данном топике выходит, что никакаких проблем с потоками не возникнет при условии, что я только читаю из любого числа потоков. 

Сегодня я некоторое время потрачу на то, чтобы сравнить разные способы организации этих потоков для енумерации по исходной строке с обычным линейным способом енумерации. Если вдруг сильно удивлюсь результатам - сообщу о них сюда.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: на результаты профилирования вполне может повлиять [cache locality](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16699282/276994). Кроме того, затраты на старт одного потока могут быть намноооого больше затрат на вычисления, так что на порциях данных меньше, скажем, 1К, я бы не запускал второй поток. (Thread pool очень помогает, да.)

Answer (score 2):

Где-то недавно читал, что обычная long-переменная (64 битная) может записываться в два подхода по 32 бита, т.е. атомарность операций над простыми типами не всегда гарантирована.

1) Касаемо массива - если не изменять указатель, через который будет происходить доступ, то элементы массива можно рассматривать как независимые. А там уже зависит от типа элементов.

2) Динамические массивы в С отсутствуют, т.е. разницы нет. "Динамичность" массивов обеспечивается специальными функциями. Стоит рассматривать их потокобезопасность. Для malloc:

> To avoid corruption in multithreaded
> applications, mutexes are used
>        internally to protect the memory-management data structures
> employed
>        by these functions.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html

3) Строки в C - это массивы символьных элементов с дополнительным элементом в конце. Такой же массив, как и остальные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. По поводу второго абзаца я примерно так себе это и представляю, но хочется услышать, как это говорят на SO, more authoritative answer.

Comment: > Динамические массивы в С отсутствуют, т.е. разницы нет. 

Я изучаю С недавно, поэтому, возможно, путаю терминологию: char arr[20] - это конечный массив, а char *arr = malloc(...) - динамический.

И разница между ними помимо фиксированности размера ещё и в том, где они аллоцируются. Насколько я знаю char arr[20] создаётся на stack, а *arr = на heap (если не считать более редкого alloca).

Comment: > To avoid corruption in multithreaded applications, mutexes are used internally to protect the memory-management data structures employed by these functions.

Можете это дополнительно прокомментировать? В смысле, что mutuxes там уже используются, и мне ни о чём не нужно заботиться, так?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich
Так или иначе, это буфер элементов некоторого типа, которые доступны независимо друг от друга. Синхронизация нужна на уровне изменения отдельно взятого элемента и работы с памятью (как я понимаю из мана, malloc синхронизирована).

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich
Судя по тексту, мьютекс используется уже внутри malloc, то есть, если у вас сразу несколько потоков будут пытаться выделять память (просто одновременно вызовут malloc), то не произойдет сбоя в менеджере памяти.

Вольная фантазия: наверняка там внутри есть какой-нибудь указатель на свободный блок в хипе и есть риск попытаться выделить дважды память в одном месте, не успев пометить ее занятой.

Comment: Да, теперь я понял, к чему вы процитировали ман, и понял, что это почти что не имеет отношения к вопросу, которыя я задал. Я интересуюсь не маллоком из разных потоков, а доступом к уже аллоцированной из главного потока строке (например, строке), к её разным элементам из разных потоков.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, `malloc()` синхронизируется лишь в том смысле, что можно не задумываясь о состоянии внутренних структур аллокатора, вызывать malloc/calloc/realloc/free... из нескольких потоков.

Но!!! Все равно нельзя делать это из асинхронных обработчиков сигналов.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich
Про malloc я говорил в контексте отличия массивов на стеке и в хипе. Всю остальную информацию я привел в ответе: различные элементы можно изменять независимо, без необходимости какой-либо синхронизации.